# Variadic templates in C++ 11 and class constructors

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am new to using C++ templates, in general and came across variadic templates and was wondering if there might be suitable for my need.

I have this code and is working fine :

```
template< typename T, typename X1, typename X2 >
class MyClass
{
    public :

    MyClass( std::shared_ptr< T > track ,
             std::shared_ptr< X1 > x1   ,
             std::shared_ptr< X2 > x2   ) ;
}

template< typename T, typename X1, typename X2 >
MyClass < T,X1,X2 >::MyClass( std::shared_ptr< T > track ,
                              std::shared_ptr< X1 > x1   ,
                              std::shared_ptr< X2 > x2   ) : d_track( track ) , d_x1( x1), d_x2( x2 )
```

but let's say I want to make it more generic - meaning that X1,X2 can be a random number - e.g. I can have X3 and X4. I want to avoid duplicating the  constructor for all different cases I might have as they are unknown as of yet - is variadic templates a solution to that?

In draft code, what I mean is something like :

```
template< typename T, typename... XS >
MyClass < T,???? >::MyClass( std::shared_ptr< T > track ,
                              std::shared_ptr< ?? > x1   ,
                              std::shared_ptr< ?? > x2   ,
                              .......) :
```

But I don't know how to express the relationship between XS and all X1...XN so that in essence when I construct my class like I do now :

```
MyClass< T, X1, X2 > local(.....)
```

this will keep working, even when I pass X3,X4 etc.

Not sure if that's possible though.

Comment: What is XS? What relationship does it have with X1...XN?

Comment: @MaxLanghof there can be None - what I want is to avoid having to add a template constructor with x1,x2,x3 - another one with x1,x2,x3,x4 etc

Answer (score 8):

You can't have a variadic number of fields d_x1, d_x2, ...; but that can be worked around by using `std::tuple`:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

template< typename T, typename... XS >
class MyClass
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> d_track;
    std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<XS>...> d_xs;
public:

    MyClass( std::shared_ptr< T > track ,
             std::shared_ptr< XS >... xs ) ;
};

template< typename T, typename... XS >
MyClass< T, XS... >::MyClass( std::shared_ptr< T > track ,
                              std::shared_ptr< XS >... xs)
    : d_track( track ) , d_xs( xs... )
{
}
```